# Call Javascript function from string

Tags: javascript, string, object

Is it possible to call a function in javascript from a string, where the function is in an object?

e.g: call "main.object.doSomething()" (notice it is a string) from the object below.

```
window.main = {
    object: {
        doSomething: function(){
            alert('Called');
       }
    }
}
```

--- Update ---

...without using eval();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.main = {
    object: {
        doSomething: function(){
            alert('Called');
       }
    }
}

function callFromString(aString) {
  var parts = aString.split(".");
  var obj = window;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
    obj = obj[parts[i]];
    if (!obj)
      return;
  }
  // strip () at the end of parts[parts.length - 1] if they are present
  if (obj[parts[parts.length - 1]])
    obj[parts[parts.length - 1]]();
}

callFromString("main.object.doSomething");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79nWH/

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this from @OverlappingElvis's idea. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`, so:

```
eval("main.object.doSomething()");
```

But `eval` is evil - try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use `eval`!** There are [many good reasons not to use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea), and most of the time there's absolutely no reason to do so. Instead, you can use the string property lookup syntax to get the method you're looking for: `main.object.doSomething()` is equivalent to `main.object['doSomething']()`. So, for example, if you want to call a function based on a string, you could do:

```
var methodToCall = 'doSomething';
main.object[methodToCall]();
```

If putting the parentheses right after the property lookup looks weird to you, you could also do `main.object[methodToCall].call(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

use eval(expression or function)

read about that in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp
or http://viralpatel.net/blogs/calling-javascript-function-from-string/

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your string like:

```
var funcString = "window.main = {
    object: {
        doSomething: function(){
            alert('Called');
       }
    }
}";
eval(funcString);
```

and if you have already your function defined in the page, you can call it with 2 different ways, using eval (which no js expert would never offer using it, you should use it just when you don't have any other option):

```
eval("main.object.doSomething()");
```

and the other way is using anonymous function:

```
Function("main.object.doSomething();")();
```